# Static IPv6 settings working on Ubuntu Server, but not on Windows Server

Tags: windows, ubuntu, networking, ipv6, connection

I experience an issue getting IPv6 to work on Windows Server whereas it is working on Ubuntu Server:

I have a VServer hosted by netcup.de with one assigned IPv4 (**37.120.aaa.bbb**) and a IPv6 subnet (**2a03:4000:xxxx:yyyy::/64**). The IPv6 gateway must be set to **fe80::1** according to the hoster.

Running a freshly installed Windows Server (2012R2/2016), if I assign a static IPv6 (**2a03:4000:xxxx:yyyy::1000**) and the specified gateway to the NIC, `ping -6 ipv6.google.com` results in timeout. There is no connection, outgoing pings result in timeouts, ingoing pings in "address not reachable". Also pinging fe80::1%4 results in timeout.

Running a freshly installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 on the same machine, if I set the static IPv6 (like I did on Windows Server) by editing /etc/network/interfaces

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
   address 2a03:4000:xxxx:yyyy::1000
   netmask 64
   gateway fe80::1
```

`ping6 ipv6.google.com` succeeds, as every outgoing and ingoing ping does (`ping6 fe80::1%eth0` also works).

tl;dr the identical IPv6-settings on the same machine work on Ubuntu Server 16.04, but not on Windows Server and I have no clue why?! Maybe I am missing some settings on Windows?! Maybe you have an idea?!

Regards Oli

Comment: Did you check that there is no other interface on windows server with link local address in fe80::/64?, Also I have been meaning to ask what is this **%4** at the end of the ping gateway? In case of Ubuntu I see its the outgoing interface, So is it the interface number on windows? If yes is it the correct interface number on which you have configured IPv6 address on?

Comment: @AnirudhMalhotra All interfaces should be using `fe80::/64` for their link-local addresses. So your question simply boils down to whether the host has more than one interface. And of course if it does have one which is connected and one which is not, then it is important to use the correct interface. The MAC address is probably the easiest thing to look for to identify the correct interface. The `%4` indicates the interface number. On Linux you are free to use interface number or interface name after the `%`, but it tends to be easier to find the name of the interface you want to use.

Comment: I only have 4 interfaces in the list: Physical NIC (%4), Loopback, Microsoft ISATAP and Teredo, so no other adapter connected to fe80::/64.

Comment: I changed my primary IPv6 address to 2a03:4000:xxxx:yyyy:37:120:aaa:bbb (my IPv6 prefix and IPv4 combined, just another IP from my 64 subnet) and I get a really weird behavior:
Ping to ipv6.google.com succeeds, pinging Googles public dns (2001:4860:4860::8888 and 8844) results in timeout again, ping to fe80::1 also timeouts. There seems to be a connection, dependent on which IPv6 is set for the adapter, but only to a variable set of hosts -.-

Comment: Does the interface show up with the same MAC address in both Linux and Windows? Do you see any problems with IPv4 connectivity? Are you sure you entered the correct prefix length when configuring the address in Windows?

Comment: I ordered another server, everything is working on it! IPv6 connections inbound, outbound, no problems. It seems there is some misconfiguration on the "problem server's" host or somewhere. Support could not identify the problem.

Comment: Very interesting! does this new server have a teredo adapter, too? :)

Comment: Yes, same config, another server!